# Google cloud npm package text to speech the FEMALE voice not working

Tags: google-cloud-api-gateway

Google cloud npm package text to speech the FEMALE voice not working but its always come with NEUTRAL voice

````
                                                                                                                                 ```
````

export async function quickStart(text) {         const request = {         input: { text: text },         // Select the language and SSML voice gender (optional)         voice: { languageCode: 'en-US'

Comment: I'm using ssmlGender: 'FEMALE' still

Comment: I also have problems with voides not working. Did you find any solutions?

Answer (score 4):

I needed to add the custom voice name to get it to work. The ssmlGender doesn't seem to have any impact on it's own anymore:

```json
voice: {
        languageCode: 'de-DE',
        ssmlGender: 'MALE', //https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/rest/v1/SsmlVoiceGender
        name:'de-DE-Standard-B',
}
```

Comment: yes, same with me. I had to add name parameter to make it work. Thanks